# What is Selenium webdriver support for firefox 23

Tags: firefox, selenium

Can anyone let me know what is the Selenium webdriver support of firefox 23 or latest.

Comment: Couldn't you just try it?

Comment: Typically latest Firefox versions break Selenium.  You're advised to always use the very latest version of Selenium, or at the very least, the version of Selenium released after the Firefox version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [**`Changelog`**](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/rb/CHANGES)

**2.35.0 (2013-08-14)**

**Firefox:**
  **Updated Firefox native event components to support Firefox 23.**